# Is it possible to use Autograd to compute the derivative of a neural network output with respect to one of its inputs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, autograd

I have a neural network model that outputs a vector Y of size approximately 4000 for about 9 inputs X. I am in need of computing the partial derivative of the output of Y with one or two of the inputs X_1 or X_2.

I already have these derivatives, and I have trained two different neural networks for either of X_1 and X_2. It does quite well, but the issue is that the derivatives are not as accurate as the neural network that computes Y.

I am hoping that there is a way to compute derivatives of the output vector Y to one of the inputs in X from the finalised/optimised neural network, such that I will not need to train two additional neural networks for the derivatives.

Is there a way of doing this with autograd?

Comment: Can you show a minimal code example? Are you using TensorFlow? Do you want to use [autograd](https://github.com/HIPS/autograd) or TensorFlow builtin automatic differentiation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean when you say that you trained separate networks for your inputs, but you can get the gradients using TensorFlow [tf.gradients](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients) op.